# get range out using sed or awk, only if given pattern match

Tags: shell, awk, sed

**Input:**

```
START
OS:: UNIX
Release: xxx
Version: xxx
END
Description about UNIX
  <Multiline>
START
OS:: LINUX
Release: xxx
Version: xxx
END
Description about LINUX
  <Multiline>
START
OS:: Windows
Release: xxx
Version: xxx
END
Description about Windows
  <Multiline>
```

Here i am trying to get all the information between START and END, only if i could match OS Type.

I can get all the data between the range START and END, however i dont know how to match the pattern

**Using SED**

```
sed -n '/START/,/END/p'
```

**using AWK**

```
awk '/START/,/END/'
```

**Expected Output**

while searching for Linux

```
START
OS:: LINUX
Release: xxx
Version: xxx
END
```

need help!!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'last~/START/ && /LINUX/ {print last; f=1} f{print} /END/{f=0} {last=$0}' file
START
OS:: LINUX
Release: xxx
Version: xxx
END
```

This approach will work even if there are lines in the input that are outside of START-END blocks.

#### How it works

- `last~/START/ && /LINUX/ {print last; f=1}`

  If the last line matches `START` and the current line matches `LINUX`, then print the last line and set variable `f` to 1.
- `f{print}`

  If `f` is nonzero, print the current line.
- `/END/{f=0}`

  If the current line matches `END`, the set `f` to zero.
- `last=$0`

  Save the current line in the variable `last`.

Comment: thanks John, works good..
i am looking for simpler as below.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="END\n"}/LINUX/' file
START
OS:: LINUX
Release: xxx
Version: xxx
END
```

It sets the input and output record separators to `END\n`, so basically there is one `START-END` block per record (well, technically `START-` not `END` as it is a record separator), and prints out the block that has `LINUX` in it. Modify the matching regex part (`/LINUX/`) to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks James, it works..
however this fails if i have data as follows:

START
OS:: UNIX
Release: xxx
Version: xxx
END
-------
........
START
OS:: LINUX
Release: xxx
Version: xxx
END
-----------
.............

Comment: If your data is something else as you presented in the OP there is a chance that it fails, yes. I presented you with a script that processes data blocks ending with `END\n`. Please update that data to the OP and I might be able to fix it.

Comment: updated Input, expected output is same.
Description can be of any number of lines :)

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '/START/{pr=$0}/LINUX/{ print pr; n=NR+3 }NR<=n{print}' file
```

The output:

```
START
OS:: LINUX
Release: xxx
Version: xxx
END
```